# MATLAB Find Strings,store in array and concatenate

Tags: arrays, matlab, find, concatenation

I have a 6x2 cell array as follows:

```
'Word1_MSW' '1234'
'Word1_LSW' '5678'
'Word2_MSW' '1234'
'Word2_LSW' '5678'
'Word3_MSW' '1234'
'Word3_LSW' '5678'
```

What I'd like to do is find all corresponding words and concatenate them automatically. For example, I'd like to find all the Word1's and concatenate them such that the MSW starts on the left like this: '12345678'. Then I'd like to store them into a new array such that I have:

```
Word1 '12345678'
Word2 '12345678'
Word3 '12345678'
```

Comment: Will they always be exactly the same format? How do they look like when the Word count is bigger than 9? `'Word134_MSW'`?

Comment: Well I have a larger cell array but only posted a subset of it for simplicity. So I could have other strings in column 1 such as 'ThisWord', 'ThisandThatWord', basically the count can vary on the first column, but the count on the second column will always be the same.

Comment: Maybe this example is too overly simplified then. Will the first column format always be `'XXXXXXXX_MSW'`? Are the only options LSW and MSW?

Comment: Yes that format will always be the same. Yes the only options are LSW and MSW.

Comment: I assume they are not in order, are they? else it is as easy as mathicg every pair

Comment: No they are not in order

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this solution, we'll first break the string in column 1 at the `'_'` using [`strtok`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strtok.html) and place the second string in a third column of `C`:

```
[C(:, 1), C(:, 3)] = strtok(C(:, 1), '_');
```

Next, sort the rows of `C` by the first column (ascending) followed by the third column (descending) using [`sortrows`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html) and find unique word strings and indices in the first column using [`unique`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html):

```
C = sortrows(C, [1 -3]);
[uniqueWords, ~, index] = unique(C(:, 1));
```

Finally, group the values in the second column using [`mat2cell`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html) and [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html), horizontally concatenate the strings in each group with [`cellfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html), and create a new cell array with the unique word strings:

```
wordGroups = mat2cell(C(:, 2), accumarray(index, 1));
out = [uniqueWords cellfun(@(c) {[c{:}]}, wordGroups)];
```

And the results for your sample `C`:

```
out =

  3×2 cell array

    'Word1'    '12345678'
    'Word2'    '12345678'
    'Word3'    '12345678'
```

Comment: `strtok`? what is this witchcraft. I was doing `cellfun(@(x) x(1:end-4), C(:,1), 'un', 0)`

Comment: @AnderBiguri: Yep, `strtok` handles cell-array-of-characters voodoo.

Answer (score 0):

The following might work, or it might at least help along the way:

```
numOfWords = 3;     % Enter number of separate 'Words'

for i=1:numOfWords
    wordNum = num2str(i);
    testWord_MSW = ['Word' wordNum '_MSW'];     % Create words to match
    testWord_LSW = ['Word' wordNum '_LSW']; 
    matchingCell_MSW = strmatch(testWord_MSW,cellArray{1}(1:end,:));    % Find matching words
    matchingCell_LSW = strmatch(testWord_LSW,cellArray{1}(1:end,:));
    concatWord = [cellArray{2}(matchingCell_MSW,:) cellArray{2}(matchingCell_LSW,:)];   % Concatenate MSW and LSW words
    finalArray{1}(i,:) = ['Word' wordNum];
    finalArray{2}(i,:) = concatWord;
end
```